# How to set utf8mb4 for mysql stored procedure parameter?

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
IN inTag varchar(767)   -- Hashtag
)
BEGIN
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
INSERT INTO test_table (s)
VALUES (inTag);
END
```

I try to call:

```
call registration.HT_test('fanart');
```

but it return

> warning 1300 Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'fanart...' 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\xA8'.

I think the problem is the parameter but I don't know how to fix it.

My project is using NodeJS and sends data to MySQL stored procedure. Please advice me how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the character set for the argument:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
IN inTag varchar(767) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test_table (s)
VALUES (inTag);
END
```